# List of 'if' switches anywhere?

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, bash-script, options

Is there a list of all the `if` switches for use in bash scripting? Sometimes I see someone using it and I wonder what the switch they're using actually does.

Example is the `-z` in this one. I know how to use it, but I don't know where it was derived from.

```
if [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    echo -e "Error: this script requires the BASH shell!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Any references, guides, posts, answers would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Ah the cardinal StackExchange sin, [cross-posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074542/list-of-if-switches-anywhere)

Comment: type `help test` in your bash shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, those are not "if switches" as you state them, but bash conditional expressions used by `[[` compound command and the `test` and `[` builtin commands.

The list is [here.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)

Comment: The list given by @1_CR can also be found using `man test`.